# How can I write a custom file loader/converter for excel?

Tags: excel, excel-interop

I'm writing a excel AddIn to load and save from json files.
I'm doing this because I didn't find any solution to have merge-able & diff-able in git.

so far, I can write a ribbon extension with 2 buttons, "load json" and "save json". this works.

But I dont like the ribbon dependency. I would like my new file format (.xlsx.json) to be added to the list of supported file format in the open file dialog.

I know that Application has FileConverters property, but it is read only.

is there a way to write my own custom FileConverter for excel?

btw, I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in C#